# Exclude 1 column in DataGridView from being populated with data from DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataTable with 4 rows. My DataGridView has 5 rows. One of that rows is a `DataGridViewCheckboxColumn`. I have to populate my DataGridView with the data from my DataTable but the `DataGridViewCheckboxColumn` column must not be touched or changed. How can I do that?

I add rows to DataGridView from a DataTable through the code below:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    myDataGridView.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of adding rows one by one use databinding:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

DataGridView will generate columns for each DataTable column. To avoid it existing columns should have DataPropertyName set:

```
for(int c = 0; c < myDataTable.Columns.Count; c++)
   myDataGridView.Columns[c+1].DataPropertyName = myDataTable.Columns[c].ColumnName;
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
```